# Sleep Function in Android

Tags: android

is there any function in android programming that can sleep the application for some time(Seconds) as well ?. I am searching this but all my efforts proved futile. Please tell me if any one knows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sleep'?

Comment: just like a sleep function in c++(Windows.h). which completely stops the application for some miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread to sleep it. Then run it again afterwards with a `new Runnable()`

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This accomplishes nothing, as only the created thread sleeps, and does nothing afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#sleep(long)

> Waits a given number of milliseconds (of uptimeMillis) before returning. Similar to sleep(long), but does not throw InterruptedException; interrupt() events are deferred until the next interruptible operation. Does not return until at least the specified number of milliseconds has elapsed.

---

```
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.
>   InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

---

The benefite of Android `SystemClock` over `Thread` is that you don't need to wrap it in the `try catch` **IF** you do not want to interrupt the sleep (it is common to not care)

Comment: isn't that a bad practice to use any kind of sleep operations in Android?

Comment: You shouldn't sleep the main (UI) thread.  For other threads it may often not be the best choice, though it can work and at times be justified.